# Ways to 'intercept' redirects to external urls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

**Scenario**

*Website* allows *users* to input content with markdown, including links.

I want to protect *users* from malicious links from other *users* by warning them that they are leaving the domain and adding a confirmation step.

**My take**

I think there are three main ways to do this.

**1 - Frontend javascript events**

Every page that has *user* generated content adds an event listener to every *anchor* element on the page. The function that runs from this event checks if the href starts with 'http'. If it does, the function [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)s and shows the warning. If it does not, the behavior runs as normal.

*Advantage:* Can use real-time components, such as modal windows, to show the warning.

*Disadvantage:* If javascript is disabled on the *user* browser, the redirect will happen normally.

**2 - Backend server routes**

Every time an *user* generates content, during the sanitation step, before saving to the database, the hyperlink attribute for any markdown link is changed from 'http://foo.bar' to '/redirect/foo.bar'.

Then, the router has method for '/redirect/:url' routes that shows a warning page.

*Advantage:* Works even if javascript is disabled on the browser.

*Disadvantage:* Shoves a middle page for any outbound request, slowing the user experience more than a modal/pop-up would.

**3 - Both**

In this approach, both approaches above are used: frontend javascript preventing default behaviors and server routes.

*Advantages:* If javascript is enabled, works in real time. If it is disabled, it still works with a traditional http request.

*Disadvantage:* A little more development time, I guess.

**Question:**

Am I on the right track? Are there any other approaches I should be aware of?

Comment: The first approach is best - since screen readers would read your URLs and not be able to index them or follow them all that well, potentially breaking SEO. The second approach is 'fine', but with a redirect header there really isn't that much more of a middle man there. Personally, I would want sites to use neither - it's blurring the neat distinctiveness and simple idea of the web, but if you have to for a UI requirement, use front-end. If you have to because of a - booo - business requirement, then the second approach is probably the best for (local) analytics.

Comment: I see. On the second and third approaches, if the middle page has a link for the actual target, would the SEO still be broken?